# How to parallelize my n queen puzzle with Pthreads?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, n-queens

I have the following Pthreads code for n-queen puzzle. It compiles successfully, but I get wrong answer. Whatever value I type I get as an answer zero. I guess I have some kind of logic error in my code. I guess the problem happens somewhere in backtracking/recursion part. If someone could suggest me a solution, I would be glad.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

int NTHREADS, SIZE; 
int *hist;
int count = 0;

int solve(int col, int tid)
{
    int start = tid * SIZE/NTHREADS;
    int end = (tid+1) * (SIZE/NTHREADS) - 1;
    int i, j;
    if (col == SIZE) 
    {
        count++;
    }

    #define attack(i, j) (hist[j] == i || abs(hist[j] - i) == col - j)
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col && !attack(i, j); j++);
        if (j < col) continue;

        hist[col] = i;
        solve(col + 1, tid);
    }

    return count;
}

void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int tid = (int)arg;
    solve(0, tid);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t* threads;
    int rc, i;

    // checking whether user has provided the needed arguments
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <number_of_queens> <number_of_threads>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }


    // passing the provided arguments to the SIZE and NTHREADS 
    // variable, initializing matrices, and allocating space 
    // for the threads
    SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);
    NTHREADS = atoi(argv[2]);
    threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(NTHREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));
    hist = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    // declaring the needed variables for calculating the running time
    struct timespec begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    // starting the run time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &begin);

    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)i);
        assert(rc == 0); // checking whether thread creation was successful
    }

    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        assert(rc == 0); // checking whether thread join was successful
    }

    // ending the run time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    // calculating time spent during the calculation and printing it
    time_spent = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    time_spent += (end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("Elapsed time: %.2lf seconds.\n", time_spent);

    printf("\nNumber of solutions: %d\n", count);

    free(hist);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using a local var for `count` in the actual 'solve' function, which should return 0 or 1 for whether a solution was not or was found respectively, then update your global counter via mutex access from the thread proc once solve has been executed. solve is recursive. treat it like it is such and follow the traditional pattern of recursive accumultation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there were quite some mistakes, but the first one really caused all to be 0. Note that your program works fine if only one thread is used.

1. Inside `solve` you split up the work per thread by computing `start` and `end`, however this should not be done once `col > 0`, because in the recursion you have to go over all rows again.
2. You share the variables `hist` and `count` amongst your threads without protecting them in a critical section, using for example semaphores. In this case you can do without the semaphores by giving each thread their own version of these variables and accumulating all the `count` entries in the join of the threads. Sharing `count` will cause problems with a low probability, but sharing is nevertheless wrong because you can not assume that `count++` is an atomic read-modify-write operation. Sharing `hist` is just algorithmically wrong.
3. If `NTHREADS` doesn't divide `SIZE` exactly, then the calculation of the last `end` does not necessarily yield `SIZE-1`.
4. If `NTHREADS > SIZE` your `start` and `end` will always be `-1`.
5. As good practice you should always check if `malloc` (and friends) don't return `NULL` as this means you ran out of memory. It is also respectful to the user of your program if you check the command line arguments for correctness.

If you solve these mistakes you will get 92 every time you run it on a regular sized chess board regardless the number of threads. Good luck.

As to code examples (asked below), I'm a bit a bit reluctant, but here you go. Personally I would have made many more changes, but I stuck closest to your code as possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

int NTHREADS, SIZE;
int ** hist = NULL;
int * count = NULL;

static void oof(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
    exit(1);
}

void solve(int col, int tid)
{
    /* If NTHREADS does not divide SIZE, you
     * will not cover all rows.
     * Also make sure SIZE >= NTHREADS, otherwise start is always 0.
     */
    int start = (col > 0) ? 0 : tid * (SIZE/NTHREADS);
    int end = (col > 0 || tid == NTHREADS-1) ? SIZE-1 : (tid+1) * (SIZE/NTHREADS) - 1;
    int i, j;
    if (col == SIZE)
    {
        count[tid]++;
    }

    #define attack(i, j) (hist[tid][j] == i || abs(hist[tid][j] - i) == col - j)
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col && !attack(i, j); j++);
        if (j < col) continue;

        hist[tid][col] = i;
        solve(col + 1, tid);
    }
}

void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int tid = (int)arg;
    count[tid] = 0;
    solve(0, tid);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t* threads;
    int rc, i, j, sum;

    // checking whether user has provided the needed arguments
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <number_of_queens> <number_of_threads>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }


    // passing the provided arguments to the SIZE and NTHREADS 
    // variable, initializing matrices, and allocating space 
    // for the threads
    SIZE = atoi(argv[1]);
    NTHREADS = atoi(argv[2]);
    threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(NTHREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));
    hist = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int*));
    count = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (hist == NULL || count == NULL) oof();
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        hist[i] = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
        if (hist[i] == NULL) oof();
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            hist[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // declaring the needed variables for calculating the running time
    struct timespec begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    // starting the run time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &begin);

    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)i);
        assert(rc == 0); // checking whether thread creation was successful
    }

    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        assert(rc == 0); // checking whether thread join was successful
        sum += count[i];
    }


    // ending the run time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

    // calculating time spent during the calculation and printing it
    time_spent = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    time_spent += (end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
    printf("Elapsed time: %.2lf seconds.\n", time_spent);

    printf("\nNumber of solutions: %d\n", sum);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        free(hist[i]);
    }
    free(hist); free(count);
    return 0;

}
```